# Extract grouped Subset with condition

Tags: r, subset

I have following data structure:

```
Group Count Value
1     1     1000
1     10    2000
2     6     1000
2     7     2000
```

Some groups that have a count value and a data value. Now I only want those rows where `count > 0.25 * sum(count of group)`.
For example group `1` has `sum(count) = 11` so the first row should not be included in the result.

Result should look like:

```
Group Count Value
1     10    2000
2     6     1000
2     7     2000
```

How can I do this in R?

Additionally my dataset has around 5 million rows. So please consider performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the sample data

```
dd<-read.table(text="Group Count Value
1     1     1000
1     10    2000
2     6     1000
2     7     2000", header=T)
```

you can do this with base R

```
subset(dd, Count>.25*ave(Count, Group, FUN=sum))
```

or the `dplyr` library

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter(Count > .25 * sum(Count))
```

perhaps you'll find one more readable. Both retrun

```
  Group Count Value
2     1    10  2000
3     2     6  1000
4     2     7  2000
```

Comment: Awesome. I was just about to post the same thing. :) Nice work!